# Illustrator: Bend 2D objects over the edges of 3D objects (extrude and bevel)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, isometric

I really like to create 3D objects with "extrude and bevel" in Illustrator CC. So is there also the possibility to achieve this? (found it [here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/30314033/-Orion-))

[image]

The objects bend over the edges and change their color. **How could I do it with extrude and bevel?** I tried to apply symbols, but they won't bend over the edges.

**If it's not possible with extrude and bevel, what's the easiest way to do it?**

Comment: Hello Act1v and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 3D Extrude & Bevel → Map Art

You can achieve this with the [**Map Art**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-3d-objects.html#mapartworktoa3dobject) feature of 3D Extrude & Bevel. You can only map artwork that has been created as a symbol. This gives you the advantage of being able to create your symbols, map them to your 3D object then update your symbols and automatically update your 3D object.

### Create your symbols

You need to create a separate symbol for each face of your 3D object. Since you want objects that overlap the edges you need to create your symbols accordingly:

[image: Flat 3D Map Artwork]

Create your symbols by dragging the art (one face at a time) to the symbols palette.

### Create the 3D Extrude

Create your 3D object (**Effect → 3D → Extrude & Bevel**). Use the **Map Artwork...** button to bring up the Map Art dialog. Toggle through each surface and select the correct symbol for that surface from the Symbol dropdown. You can transform, move, rotate & scale the symbol to fit the surface.

[image: 3D Extrude & Map Artwork Options]

### Final 3D Mapped Object

[image: Final 3D Object]

Comment: WOW! This answer is just perfect! With all the pictures and the steps, and you even made the same style in the picture. I love you CAI :)

Comment: @Act1v Glad to help :)